# RNA-seq Data on domestic animal with different environment

Tags: bioinformatics, rna, rna-sequencing

I want to find the **RNAseq** data available on domestic animals in different environments. If **microarray** data is available, it would be more useful. If you know I would appreciate to inform me.

Answer (score 3):

There is something called [GEO](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/), which is maintained by the NIH and is a massive collection of data obtained from RNA seq, microarray, etc. experiments. One thing you can do is search for a paper that has done what you are looking for. The paper may have a GEO accession number, and you can use that number at the GEO website to find the data you want. You may also search GEO directly but Im not too familiar with it. It may just be easier to find a paper with a GEO accession number.

Comment: There's also the [ArrayExpress](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/) database maintained by the EBI.